# Why is SelectedItem Cleared When Changing ItemsSource Using a DataTrigger When the Item Exists in Both Sources?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

All code is C# & XAML using .NET Framework 4.6.1.

***Minimal, Reproducable Example***

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Application x:Class="ComboBoxSwapTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Application.Resources />
</Application>
```

**App.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace ComboBoxSwapTest
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            var vm = new ViewModel();
            var window = new MainWindow() { DataContext = vm };
            window.Show();

            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Option.cs**

```cs
namespace ComboBoxSwapTest
{
    public class Option
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Number { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string NumberName { get { return string.Format("{0} - {1}", Number, Name); } }

        public string NameNumber { get { return string.Format("{1} - {0}", Number, Name); } }
    }
}
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```cs
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;

namespace ComboBoxSwapTest
{
    public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        private bool _nameFirst = true;
        public bool NameFirst
        {
            get { return _nameFirst; }
            set
            {
                if (_nameFirst != value)
                {
                    _nameFirst = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(NameFirst));
                }
            }
        }

        public List<Option> Options { get; }
        public List<Option> NameNumberOptions
        {
            get { return Options.OrderBy(s => s.Name).ThenBy(s => s.Number).ToList(); }
        }
        public List<Option> NumberNameOptions
        {
            get { return Options.OrderBy(s => s.Number).ThenBy(s => s.Name).ToList(); }
        }

        private Option _selectedOption;
        public Option SelectedOption
        {
            get { return _selectedOption; }
            set
            {
                if (_selectedOption != value)
                {
                    _selectedOption = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedOption));
                }
            }
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            Options = new List<Option>();
            Options.Add(new Option() { Id = 1, Name = "Foo", Number = "111" });
            Options.Add(new Option() { Id = 2, Name = "Bar", Number = "222" });
            Options.Add(new Option() { Id = 3, Name = "Baz", Number = "333" });
        }
    }
}
```

**InvertBoolConverter.cs**

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace ComboBoxSwapTest
{
    public class InvertBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return !(bool)value;
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Class="ComboBoxSwapTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ComboBoxSwapTest"
        Title="Main">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:InvertBoolConverter x:Key="InvertBoolConverter" />
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <RadioButton GroupName="Toggle"
                         Content="Name First"
                         IsChecked="{Binding Path=NameFirst}" />
            <RadioButton GroupName="Toggle"
                         Content="Number First"
                         IsChecked="{Binding Path=NameFirst, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolConverter}}" />
        </StackPanel>
        <ComboBox IsEditable="False" IsReadOnly="False"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedOption}">
            <ComboBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NameFirst}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="NameNumber" />
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=NameNumberOptions}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=NameFirst}" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="DisplayMemberPath" Value="NumberName" />
                            <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=NumberNameOptions}" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ComboBox.Style>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System.Windows;

namespace ComboBoxSwapTest
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Steps to Reproduce:**
1) Start Application.
2) Select an item from the drop down.
3) Change the radio button to Number First.

At this point, the item is still selected, but it is in a different format, and is using a list instance with a different sort.

4) Change the radio button back to Name First.

Now the item is no longer selected, while we are back to a list instance with the original sort.

---

That brings us to the title question: Why is SelectedItem cleared when changing ItemsSource using a DataTrigger when the item exists in both sources?

Note that I'm not looking for a philosophical why, as in why is the framework designed this way. I'm looking for the place in the framework design that causes this behavior.

I've tried to debug using decompiled sources, but a lot of variable values are optimized away so it's pretty hard to follow.

Here's some interesting things to try starting from the base example in each scenario:

---

Change the order of the data triggers.  Now, the SelectedItem is cleared when switching to Number First, but it is preserved when switching to Name First.

---

Adding this line to the ComboBox's Style alongside the DataTriggers causes the SelectedItem to be preserved in both directions:

```xml
<Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=Options}" />
```

---

Expose a list like this:

```cs
public List<Option> SortedOptions
{
    get { return NameFirst ? NameNumberOptions : NumberNameOptions; }
}
```

Make NameFirst indicate this property has changed as well, then bind to it instead of using DataTriggers.  Again, the SelectedItem is preserved in both directions.

---

Change to using CollectionViewSources that are bound to the basic Options list, set the ComboBox's IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to False, and then swap between those sources with the DataTriggers.  You get the same behavior where the SelectedItem clears.

---

Note that my actual solution uses CollectionViewSources to sort the lists and includes the "baseline" ItemsSource to workaround the lost selection.  However, I'm still curious about why this behavior exists.

Comment: Hey! Your question is very detailed and thorough, but what kind of answer are you looking for? As things stand, a direct one would be "because the framework is designed that way, and why is that we'll likely never get to know".

Comment: @ArtemK It's more of a curiosity question where I'd like to know what the gap is.  If that also reveals the "why", that's a bonus.  I'm thinking this is more of a bug than an intentional framework design.  Everything works as expected when it's done in the view model or when a "base case" is provided, and it *sometimes* works based on the order of the triggers.  To me, that implies that there's a gap somewhere where ItemsSource gets set to null, which auto-clears SelectedItem.  I don't know if it would ever be fixed because .NET Core becomes the primary implementation starting in 2020.